# Create a static fade at the bottom of a background image

Tags: html, css, background, gradient, fade

I've set a property for the body, setting for it a background of a fixed width and height, but with a vertical offset of a certain amount of pixels. However, with larger screens it may be possible that the background image would end, resulting in a white background under it.

Is it possible to create a white static fade effect at the bottom end of the image, so that no-body with any screen resolution would notice the end of the image?

I tryed with

```
-moz-linear-gradient(to bottom,
        rgba(255,255,255,0) 80%,
        rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%
      ),
```

however, since the offset can change dynamically, I've found some difficulties to keep the gradient and the background aligned.

Could you suggest me a quicker way to achieve this result? (or may be another technique to bypass the background-end issue)

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: https://codepen.io/lauraeddy/pen/aLYLGX

HTML:

```html
<div class="image">
    <img src="/your-image"/>
    <div class="fade"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.image {
    position: relative;
}
.image img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
}
.image .fade {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    z-index: 2;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)
        linear-gradient(
            to bottom,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 80%
        )
        repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

This way, you are aligning the `fade` element to the bottom of the `.image` div which should be the height of the image element.

You may need to change the height of the `.image .fade` div to whatever looks best.